# How can I analyse data on PostgreSQL using the origin table and expectant table I have described below?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

This is how my data looks like:

| Item | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hat | 2020 | 15 |
| Hat | 2021 | 17 |
| Hat | 2022 | 19 |
| Pen | 2020 | 3 |
| Pen | 2021 | 2 |
| Pen | 2022 | 3.3 |

I want to use PostgreSQL to achieve a simple data analysis task that will provide the result below:

| Item | Year | Price | Previous Year | Previous price | higher_than_previous_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hat | 2020 | 15 |  |  |  |
| Hat | 2021 | 17 | 2020 | 15 | yes |
| Hat | 2022 | 19 | 2021 | 17 | yes |
| Pen | 2020 | 3 |  |  |  |
| Pen | 2021 | 2 | 2020 | 3 | no |
| Pen | 2022 | 3.3 | 2021 | 2 | yes |

**Previous Year:** Fetches the closest year that is lesser than the current year specified in the year column.
**Previous Price:** Fetches the price for the item that corresponds with the previous year.
**higher_than_previous_year:** compares the price column with the previous price column and computes yes when the price is higher than the previous price and no when the previous price is higher than the year price.

I will appreciate it if any PostgreSQL guru can take a crack at this. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Also, for the last record, it should be `yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [lag window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), which allows you to look back the previous row(s). Since this requires several look back operation, you define and use a WINDOW definition in the query. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=facea197c06062976bb71228e4c624d6))

```
select item, year, price 
     , lag(year)  over w  previous_year
     , lag(price) over w  previous_price
     , case when price > lag(price) over w  then 'Yes' 
            when lag(price) over w   is null then null::text  
            else 'No'
       end higher_than_previous_year
  from origin
window w as (partition by item order by year);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful. I read up on lag() and lead() window functions and used them with partition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple `JOINS` and `UNION` to achieve this (one of the many ways):

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    a.item, 
    a.year, 
    a.price, 
    NULL AS prev_year, 
    NULL AS prev_price,
    NULL AS higher_than_previous_year
FROM
    (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Year) as rn
    from t
    ) as a
WHERE rn=1

UNION

SELECT 
    a.item, 
    a.year, 
    a.price, 
    b.year as prev_year, 
    b.price as prev_price,
  CASE
    WHEN a.price > b.price THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'No'
  END AS higher_than_previous_year
FROM 
    (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Year) as rn
    from t
    ) as a
LEFT JOIN
    (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Year) as rn
    from t
    ) as b
  ON a.item=b.item and a.rn=b.rn+1
WHERE a.rn>1
```

**Explanation:**

1. First creating a `ROW_NUM` column to find prev rows - Using the same table in all the places wherever `FROM` and `JOIN` is being used
2. **Above `UNION`:** Getting rows with 1 as they are quite easy to go ahead
3. **Below `UNION`:** Self joining the table to get it's prev values

See fiddle in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f053f21739a8bb9974504878311b6859)*

If you have access, I would suggest to create `intermediate tables` so that the query looks simpler. See this *[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6993935f001f5d1444908625cd2ffdcf)* (created intermediate tables so query is easy to understand and debug)

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy response. I tried out your suggestion but I am unable to achieve the same result with my original dataset. I tried to create a simplified version of what I am working with and now, using this same logic in my current dataset is not giving me the desired result.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is going wrong and at which step?

Comment: I am looking at the fiddle you created and it is really helping me see things clearly. I want to add that my original dataset has another column called category that describes the types of the items under review.

Comment: Got it.. But Wish to know what's the error or what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I stated earlier in one of my comments to @arun's solution that there was an extra column called 'category'. I found that this query worked best.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN price > previous_price THEN 'yes'
     WHEN price <= previous_price THEN 'no'
     ELSE null
END AS is_current_year_price_higher
FROM
    (
SELECT *,
LAG(year,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item, category ORDER BY item, year) AS previous_year,
LAG(price,1) OVER (PARTITION BY item, category ORDER BY item, year) AS previous_price
FROM table_name
    ) AS main
```